# How do I sync my google photos using the photos app?

Tags: photos

I need to sync my Google photos (preferably the default photos app.)
How can I do this?
Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any built-in way of syncing however, I would give overgrive a look they've got a 14 day trial and its $4.99 for a license. Basically integrates Google Drive into your desktop and by some parallels possibly your Google photos.

Answer (score 0):

google-drive-ocamlfuse integrates your google drive (and photos of course) with your desktop. It works perfectly fine and is free. However you would have to import the pics into pantheon-photos. (no direct integration).
How to set it up is explained in detail here (or google it):
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/mount-google-drive-in-linux-with-google.html